# Failed to start Kibana on AWS machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm following [blog post](http://126kr.com/article/61ghk47m3im) about using ELK stack. Machine for instalation is an amazon small Ubuntu instance.
I got to the point when I need to install **Kibana** service so I run:

```
sudo apt-get install kibana
```

Then I changed in `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

```
 server.port: 5601
 elasticsearch.url: "0.0.0.0:9200"
```

since I can get response from elasticsearch `sudo curl 0.0.0.0:9200`
then I run

```
sudo service kibana start
```

And after running `sudo service kibana status` I receiving:

```
x@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/$ sudo service kibana status
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-12-02 13:52:55 UTC; 13ms ago
 Main PID: 5921 (node)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 1.1M
      CPU: 3ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─5921 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Dec 02 13:52:55 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
x@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/$ sudo service kibana status
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx kibana[5921]:         buildSha: '8f2ace746d1b84702bb618308efa65dc0c3f8a34' },
Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx kibana[5921]:      dev: { basePathProxyTarget: 5603 },
Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx kibana[5921]:      pid: { exclusive: false },
Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 02 13:52:56 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 02 13:52:57 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 13:52:57 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Dec 02 13:52:57 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 02 13:52:57 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
```

Unfortunatelly log is not created under directory `/var/log/kibana`even after setting rights by `chown kibana:kibana /var/log/kibana`:

```
 ll /var/log/kibana/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 kibana kibana 4096 Dec  2 10:20 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 root   syslog 4096 Dec  2 09:50 ../
```

First of all I wish to see Kibana log (whole problem resolution will be even better :) )

Comment: did you install elasticsearch first and run with 9200 port?

Comment: Yes - and checked it -was up and running.